# How to check folder / file permissions with Pathlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

Is there a Pathlib equivalent of `os.access()`?

Without Pathlib the code would look like this:

```py
import os
os.access('my_folder', os.R_OK)  # check if script has read access to folder
```

However, in my code I'm dealing with Pathlib paths, so I would need to do this (this is just an example):

```py
# Python 3.5+
from pathlib import Path
import os

# get path ~/home/github if on Linux
my_folder_pathlib = Path.home() / "github"
os.access(str(my_folder_pathlib), os.R_OK)
```

The casting to `str()` is kinda ugly.
I was wondering if there is a **pure Pathlib solution** for what I'm trying to achieve?

p.s. I'm aware of the principle "easier to ask for forgiveness", however this is part of a bigger framework, and I need to know as soon as possible if the script has the right permissions to a NAS stored folder.

Answer (score 9):

From Python 3.6, `os.access()` accepts path-like objects, therefore no `str()` needed anymore:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.access

Although this is still not a pure Pathlib solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use the stat() method on a Path object, then lookup the st_mode attribute.

`Path().stat().st_mode`

Comment: How do I interpret the output of st_mode? Can't find any docs...

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html